# Correct sequence of python functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I wrote a very basic python code, but it didn't work:

```
str = "asddasdvsatvsyvcstvcsacvsacvsaifteiopvnvbcshavsdsdzasbbnyju"
dict = {}
for i in str:
    dict[i] = dict.get(i,0)+1

print(list(dict.items()).sort())
```

then I just changed the sequence of functions and separated them, and surprisingly it worked!

```
str = "asddasdvsatvsyvcstvcsacvsacvsaifteiopvnvbcshavsdsdzasbbnyju"
dict = {}
for i in str:
    dict[i] = dict.get(i,0)+1

mylist = list(dict.items())
mylist.sort()    
print(mylist)
```

What's happened from my first to second code that makes it work?

Comment: str in Python is a built-in type. Please don't not use str as variable.

Comment: `dict` is also a built-in type. Should never be used as variable, in fact I'm surprised the code works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.sort()` sorts the list in-place (it changes the list itself and doesn't make a copy). But it doesn't *return* anything (other than None).

If you do

```
print(list(dict.items()).sort())
```

You print the return value of `sort()` -- which is None.

But with

```
mylist.sort()    
print(mylist)
```

You first sort, and then you print the value of `mylist`. That's what you want.

You could also have done

```
print(sorted(mylist))
```

But that leaves `mylist` unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort()` sorts the list in place but returns `None`, that's why in the first example you're seeing `None` printed out.

You could use built-in `sorted`, that works exactly the same but creates and returns new list.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` returns nothing. Therefore, `print(l.sort())` prints nothing.

However, `l.sort()`, and therefore `print(l.sort())`, **does** sort the `l` 
list.

Therefore, printing `l` after `l.sort()` has been executed will print something, namely, the `l` list sorted.